# Android onTouchListener does not work from nested switch statement

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing a trivia game for android. A random number is generated to select a question at random. When i get to my nested switch statements eclipse gives an error "v cannot be resolved" from this part: 
    `switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button0:
                    Toast.makeText(BeginGame.this, "success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                    default:
                      Toast.makeText(BeginGame.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      break;`

Any suggestions?

`public class BeginGame extends Activity  {

```
 public OnTouchListener nextListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("base", "next");
        }
        return false;
        }
 };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        int[] questionArray = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
        Random questionNumberGenerated = new Random();
        int num;
        boolean duplicate = false;


        do{
            num = questionNumberGenerated.nextInt(7);
                for (int i=0; i<questionArray.length; i++){

                    if (num == questionArray[i]){
                        duplicate=true;
                        }
                    }
                }while (duplicate);

        if (duplicate=false){
            for (int j=0; j<questionArray.length; j++)
                questionArray[j]=num;
        }






        switch (num) {
        case 0:             
            Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
            button0.setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
            Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button3.setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            text.setText("press alabama:");
            button0.setText("Alabama");
            button1.setText("Mississippi");
            button2.setText("Philadelphia");
            button3.setText("Virginia");    
                switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button0:
                    Toast.makeText(BeginGame.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(BeginGame.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                    break;
            }
        case 1:  
            text.setText("press green");
            button0.setText("zsx");
            button1.setText("zczcz");
            button2.setText("zczc");
            button3.setText("green");
        case 2:  
            text.setText("press blue");
            button0.setText("www");
            button1.setText("aaa");
            button2.setText("dddd");
            button3.setText("blue");
        case 3:  
            text.setText("press red");
            button0.setText("111");
            button1.setText("222");
            button2.setText("3333");
            button3.setText("red");
        }
    }
```

}

`

Comment: Either you havent provided full src code, or you don't have declared v in your code.

Comment: Can you tell me how to declare "v"?

Comment: Go back to the code you simply copied this from, and read it to understand what it means by v.

Comment: Yes. v is the name of a variable defined in the code that you copied this from.  It's not some special syntax - it's just a variable, and probably a parameter as Raj attempted to explain.

Comment: What you stated is obvious to me. I don't have that much code to sift through. I am "simply" expressing that I cannot find a solution. Do not mistake asking for help as blissful ignorance. Do you have any android development experience?

Comment: I'm none of a boss who could fire you, an instructor who could reduce your grade, a colleague who could complain about you, or a likely customer who could give you one star.  So I don't care about your programming practices, and your pretentious responses are out of place.  Again: want to know what that 'v' is that's mysteriously in your code? Then return to where you copied it from.

Comment: Do you have any android development experience? Are you unable to provide an answer for my problem? I came here as a last resort. The answer is not in the code I "simply copied this from".

Answer (score 1):

what you wants to do exactly? there is no definition of v in that method.
if you wants to perform some task on button touch move the that switch case to onTouch method like following.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button0:
                Toast.makeText(BeginGame.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(BeginGame.this, "Fail",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Raj. I understand what you pointed out. When the random number comes up, it will correspond to case in the outer part of the switch statement. that case will set up the text and buttons that are to be shown on the screen. The inner switch statement for that case is to determine if the touched answer is correct. the program is not finished - I'm just stuck on v.getId.